# IOS loading a tableview with data

Tags: objective-c, ios, tableview

I'm fairly new to iOS and have much more to learn, and hope you guys can guide me from my mistake.

I've recently learned passing data from TableView to DetailView, and thought, why not the other way around. I also start building a StopWatch app, and felt that a log function would be very useful.

With that said, I'm currently building a stopwatch app that works as a timer and have a high score log function. It goes from View(stopwatch) to tableView(log board) I'm using a NSMutableArray as a temp storage to hold the information as they should be lost when the app start/close. Unfortunately, it seem that by following and changing variable here and there, i got myself confuse and stuck now.

Thanks for the suggestion and help you guys gave and thanks @Abizern for giving me tips. Manage to solve all the problem. Shall leave the code here incase anyone in the future do similar things to this.

TimerViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SampleData.h"
#import "SampleDataDAO.h"
#import "HighScoreTableViewController.h"
@interface TimerViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSTimer *stopWatchTimer; // Store the timer that fires after a certain time
    NSDate *startDate; // Stores the date of the click on the start button
}
@property(nonatomic, strong) SampleDataDAO *daoDS;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *ds;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *stopWatchLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *onStartPressed;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *onStopPressed;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *onLogPressed;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *onHighscorePressed;

- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)onLogPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)onHighscorePressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

TimerViewController.m

```
#import "TimerViewController.h"

@interface TimerViewController ()

@end

@implementation TimerViewController
@synthesize stopWatchLabel;
@synthesize onStartPressed;
@synthesize onStopPressed;
@synthesize onLogPressed;
@synthesize onHighscorePressed;
@synthesize ds,daoDS;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    daoDS = [[SampleDataDAO alloc] init];
    self.ds = daoDS.PopulateDataSource;
    onStopPressed.enabled=false;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setStopWatchLabel:nil];
    [self setOnStartPressed:nil];
    [self setOnLogPressed:nil];
    [self setOnStopPressed:nil];
    [self setOnHighscorePressed:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        HighScoreTableViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.arrayOfSampleData = self.ds;
   }
}



- (void)updateTimer
{
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.S"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    stopWatchLabel.text = timeString;

}

- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender {
    startDate = [NSDate date];

    // Create the stop watch timer that fires every 10 ms
    stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
    onStartPressed.enabled=false;
    onStopPressed.enabled=true;
}

- (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender {
    [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    stopWatchTimer = nil;
    [self updateTimer];
    onStartPressed.enabled=true;
}   

- (IBAction)onLogPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString * timeCaptured = stopWatchLabel.text;

    static NSInteger i = 1  ;
        SampleData* mydata = [[SampleData alloc]init];

        mydata.clueName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"clue %d",i++ ];
        mydata.timeLog = timeCaptured;
        [self.ds addObject:mydata];


        NSLog(@"%@",mydata.clueName);
        NSLog(@"time %@", mydata.timeLog);
        NSLog(@"%d",[self.ds count]);
        mydata=nil;
    }

- (IBAction)onHighscorePressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Proceeding to HighScore");
}



@end
```

HighScoreTableView.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "SampleData.h"
    #import "SampleDataDAO.h"
    #import "TimerViewController.h"
    @interface HighScoreTableViewController : UITableViewController
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOfSampleData;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) SampleData * highscoreData;
    @end


HighScoreTableView.m

#import "HighScoreTableViewController.h"

@interface HighScoreTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation HighScoreTableViewController
@synthesize highscoreData;
@synthesize arrayOfSampleData;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    highscoreData = [[SampleData alloc]init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.arrayOfSampleData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"highscoreCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //highscoreData = [self.arrayOfSampleData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

highscoreData = (SampleData *)[self.arrayOfSampleData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  //if above line doesn't work, use this
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ time %@",highscoreData.clueName, highscoreData.timeLog];
return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

SampleData.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SampleData : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString * clueName;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString * timeLog;
@end
```

SampleData.m

```
#import "SampleData.h"

@implementation SampleData
@synthesize clueName,timeLog;
@end
```

SampleDataDAO.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SampleData.h"
@interface SampleDataDAO : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * someDataArray;

-(NSMutableArray *)PopulateDataSource;
@end
```

SampleDataDAO.m   (Not sure if this DAO NSObject is needed)

```
#import "SampleDataDAO.h"

@implementation SampleDataDAO
@synthesize someDataArray;

-(NSMutableArray *)PopulateDataSource
{
    someDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    SampleData * mydata = [[SampleData alloc] init];


   mydata = nil;


    return someDataArray;
} 
@end
```

Comment: You failed to define ```SampleDataDAO``` in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several missteps in your coding:

1. You do need to use `prepareForSegue` to pass data from parent to child view controller.  In your case from `TimerViewController` to `HighScoreTableViewController`.
2. In your `HighScoreTableViewController` class, create an iVar array that will hold the array of `sampleData` that you will pass over from `TimerViewController` instant via the `prepareForSeque`.  Something like this:

HighScoreTableViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrayOfSampleData;
```

3 . In your `prepareForSeque` of the `TimerViewController`, this line is wrong:

//TimerViewController.highscoreData = [self.ds objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];

Try this:

```
detailViewController.arrayOfSampleData = self.ds;
```

4 .  In the HighScoreTableViewController.m, under viewDidLoad, replace this

```
highscoreData = (SampleData *)self.highscoreData;
```

with:

```
highscoreData = [SampleData alloc]init];
```

5 .  In numberOfRowsInSection, you now can do this:

```
return self.arrayOfSampleData.count;
```

6 .  In the cellForRowAtIndexPath,

```
highscoreData = [self.arrayOfSampleData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//highscoreData = (SampleData *)[self.arrayOfSampleData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  //if above line doesn't work, use this

cell.textLabel.text = @"%@ time %@ ", highscoreData.clueName, highscoreData.timeLog;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `HighScoreTableViewController` you need access to your array e.g. by declaring and defining a writable property:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArr;
```

then you can define

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [self.myArr count];
}
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // ... like in your code

    // Tried changing variable here and there base on tutorial, but can't seem to get it right.** 

    SampleData * sample = (SampelData *) [self.myArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"%@ time %@ ",sample.clueName, sample.timeLog;
    NSLog(@"Cell Value %d %@",indexPath.row,  cell.textLabel.text);
    return cell;
}
```

So basically you just have to change two lines in the definitions of your methods. Most of the time you work with TableViews it is like this: assign the array you want to read data from to a custom property. Return the size of the array in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and take an object from the appropiate index to populate a cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

If the contents of your array changes you have to do extra action to update your table view.

Answer (score 1):

- First declare the array in .h file(ex. `NSMutableArray *arrStopwatchDetails`).
- Create the property of that array like `@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *arrStopwatchDetails`.
- Synthesize the array in .m file like `@synthesize arrStopwatchDetails`.
- Allocate the array in viewDidLoad or before you want to used.

  ex. `self.arrStopwatchDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`
- In `numberOfRowsInSection` method, return the count of array similar to return `[self.arrStopwatchDetails count]`.
- `In cellForRowsAtIndexPath` method, assign value of array element to the cell text as

SampleData * sample = [[[SampleDataDAO alloc]init ].self.arrStopwatchDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = @"%@ time %@ ",sample.clueName, sample.timeLog;
Thats it.